# What is the main reasons to use Miltersen & Schartz (1998) model for commodity futures options

Tags: options, black-scholes, models, factor-models, commodities

versus a standard Generalised Black and Scholes model (if there are any?)

I have read the paper but I am not to sure about its practical implications as would people with more experience using this model.

**Source**: http://people.oregonstate.edu/~thomanen/Geo599/Schwartz_Miltersen.pdf

Comment: Note that it is a very widely cited paper, not a crazy model coming from nowhere